# ASP.NET Core Minimal API POST verb raw body swagger empty parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, minimal-apis

I'm using an ASP.NET Core Minimal API, the `POST` operation reads raw data:

```
app.MapPost("/Authenticate", async (HttpRequest Request) => {
    string rawContent = string.Empty;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body,
                    encoding: Encoding.UTF8, detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: false))
    {
        rawContent = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
    // .......
})
.WithName("Authenticate")
.WithOpenApi();
```

When I run `dotnet run` command and it opens the browser with the Swagger UI, the endpoint parameters are not available, the endpoint works perfect using Postman + raw post data, but it would be nicer if Swagger UI would allow me to input the raw post body too...

Thank you

Tried with interfaces as input, same result, empty parameters @ Swagger UI ...

Comment: Is there a particular why do you want to read the body manually via stream?

Comment: Do you know any other way to deal with raw data?

Comment: Is there any particular why do you want raw data here?

Comment: That's how the client will post the data using raw data... I have multiple clients / partners where their API works with raw data, nothing new.. or probably too classic in other programming languages...

Comment: So you are saying that your clients can post any type of JSON with any structure without any kind of contract?

Comment: Yes and no, the structure is dynamic, that's why dynamic was created, no ? Anyways ... thanks for your time to review my question...

Comment: There are other ways to handle dynamic structures then reading from the body directly. Depends on what you need to do with it after.

Comment: I would love to learn about them if you dont mind to share those "other ways" , thank you...

Comment: Can you please share a bit more info what do you actually do with `rawContent`. There are cases when actually just reading the stream can be way to go.

Comment: It's not json data or xml, custom structures defined between parties, can be binary or encoded using sha-1 ...

Comment: What content type are you using?

Comment: text 99% of the time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the OpenAPI to include a requestBody schema that accepts raw data. Here is an example you can use as a reference:

```
app.MapPost("/Authenticate", async (HttpRequest Request) =>
{
    string rawContent = string.Empty;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body,
                    encoding: Encoding.UTF8, detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: false))
    {
        rawContent = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
    
})
.WithName("Authenticate")
.WithOpenApi(openApi =>
{
    openApi.RequestBody = new OpenApiRequestBody
    {
        Content = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiMediaType>
        {
            {
                "application/json", new OpenApiMediaType
                {
                    Schema = new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Type = "object" 
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        Description = "JSON"
    };

    return openApi;
});
```

[image]

[image]